# Android SDK for ARM

Tags: android, arm

So, there are two popular ARM laptops (google chromebooks) and they are fanless (that is crucial for me, because I like the silence).

I want to be able to develop java and android applications (with NDK possibly) on this laptops with external display (so would have a lot of space for my code on screen).

There is JAVA SDK for ARM, and there is eclipse for ARM, but as far as I know there is no Android SDK for ARM.

But I've found on xda, that there is some way of developing android apps on ChromeOS. And with AIDE it could be developed right on the android device itself. So maybe I'm wrong, and there is some way to do it on Ubuntu on ARM platform?

Or if there is no Android SDK for ARM, then it should be! Where can I make a petition to google, to develop it? It shouldn't be that hard, just recompile it for ARM, probably.

Comment: Just install Ubuntu: http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html

Comment: And answered properly on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/591151/running-a-linux-based-distribution-on-a-samsung-chromebook

Comment: I wasn't asking how to install some port of ubuntu to chromebook. I know that we can do it (It had a bad performance with video previously as there were no GPU drivers though).
I am asking about developing Android apps on such device.

Comment: Ultimately this should be possible - it's just a matter of making the effort to get it all working.  However, this site is about questions - so what is the actual questions *which can be answered* here?

Comment: There are two question in my post. You can seee them by the "?" sign in the end of the sentence =)

Comment: Putting a "?" after a vague uncertainty does not make a question.

Comment: A question is a linguistic expression used to make a request for information, or the request made using such an expression (by wiki).
So by this definition how is this "So maybe I'm wrong, and there is some way to do it on Ubuntu on ARM platform?" is not a question?

Comment: If you want a fanless, long life PC, you can get an Acer W3 tablet. With the keyboard attached you can get almost 20 hours of silent use of a REAL Windows PC and not waste time trying to cobble together unsupported scenarios.

Comment: That's a good alternative, actually. So maybe I'll actually do that.
But I wanted a linux tablet, actually...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So maybe I'm wrong, and there is some way to do it on Ubuntu on ARM platform?

You are welcome to download the relevant tools source code (e.g., **`aapt`**) and work on porting and cross-compiling them to ARM. Or, see if the AIDE folk have posted theirs for download. Or, see if anyone else has posted cross-compiled tools. Or see if the AIDE folk are planning on releasing theirs.

> Where can I make a petition to google, to develop it?

You are welcome to dance naked in front of the Googleplex. I think the Android team is in [Building 44](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_lawn_statues).

Note that dancing naked may be against the law in Mountain View, CA.

Or, if you prefer, you can [file an enhancement request](http://b.android.com), in which case the naked dancing could merely be a way of drawing attention to the issue. Or perhaps drawing attention to other things.

> It shouldn't be that hard, just recompile it for ARM, probably.

Then clearly you can do it yourself, allowing Google to focus on doing things that we in the community cannot do quite so readily.

Comment: Can I? Very probably I can. But should I spent my time on it as a developer to create tools for me? I don't think so. I got things to do and its not time efficient, because I would clearly spend more time, than a specialist.

Comment: Could passiveness regarding ARM be a political thing since the Russians have decided to abandon Intel and base all government computers on ARM.  We I have seen a tutorial somewhere on the net where a guy actually recompiled the tools source for ARM and made it work. I tried repeating it myself on an ARM Chromebook but the Android source download exceeded the size of my SD card so I lost steam.

Comment: Hereś the URL to the mentioned guide: http://www.timelesssky.com/blog/building-android-sdk-build-tools-aapt-for-debian-arm